# sgetn declared deprecated

Tags: c++

I need to change the sgetn to _Sgetn_s in boost header file here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp I don't know what the function does so i'm afraid to edit it myself.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change it? Can you describe what it is you are doing and what the problem is?

Comment: Yes! I'm getting a compiler warning "sgetn declared deprecated"

Comment: You want change boost header file? bad idea. Why this warning forces you to do that?

Comment: Can you post a small program which produces the warning?

Comment: I've just checked the draft version of the standard. `sgetn` is _still_ not deprecated and `_Sgetn_s` is not part of the public interface to `std::basic_streambuf` so I don't think that you do need to - or should - make this change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you editing the header file directly, but instead you can put the flag /wd4996 in command-line options in MSVS to supress the related warnings.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfahxw6k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) you can read more about different levels of warnings on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

As Charles says, `sgetn` is not deprecated, and even the draft C++0x standard recommends specific uses for it. Recommend you look at your implementation's code for `basic_streambuf`, find the declaration or flag that makes it deprecated, and look for a preprocessor flag to disable it.